# Writing a for-loop in R that populates a matrix with the output of a correlation test (estimates and confidence intervals)?

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, correlation

As the title suggests, I would like to wrtie a for-loop in R that takes one variable as given (a), creates 10 different permutations of a second one (b), calculates a correlation test and stores the output (correlation estimates and confidence intervals) in a dataframe or matrix. That matrix should consequently comprise three columns (estimate, lower, upper) and 10 rows.

After that, I would like to plot the output, using ggplot to display every correlation test as a
`geom_point() + geom_linerange(lower, upper)` with a reference line at `yintercept=0`.

```
a <- 1:100
b <- c(rep(0,100))
data <- matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 10)

for (i in 1:10) {
  b[i] <- sample(100, replace = FALSE)
  temp <- cor.test(a,b)
  correlation <- as.numeric(temp$estimate)
  lower <- as.numeric(temp$conf.int[1])
  upper <- as.numeric(temp$conf.int[2])
  data[i,] <- c(correlation[i], lower[i], upper[i])
  print(data)
  #ggplot(data, aes(x=paste0("correlation_",[i]), y=correlation)) + 
     #geom_point(color="red") + 
     #geom_linerange(ymin=lower, ymax=upper, color="red") + 
     #geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype="dashed")
}
```

For some reason, that doesn't work. I'm guessing that it has to do with the way I'm attempting to store the output of the correlation test results in `data`. The for-loop, as it is now, creates 10 matrices, the first of which contains all the output and then from the second onward gradually dropping one row until all but the first are `NA`. Also, I'm not sure the `ggplot()` call would work as it is now.

Could someone help?

Comment: The code is sorta messed up at the beginning.  If you are going to use `b` in a loop you don't need to initialize it with values. `b <- numeric()` is sufficient.  And the `b[i] <- sample(100, replace = FALSE)` fails because you don't specify the ranges of values to be sampled.  `data` can be collected as a vector and then used to populate a dimensioned matrix after the loop completes.  Suggest updating the question to get more assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `b[i]` does not work because *b* is a numeric vector and you try to assign another vector (with length 100) to the i-th element of *b*. You also don´t need to initialize *b* beforehand. Just `b <- sample(1:100, replace = FALSE)` in the loop would suffice.

Second, `c(correlation[i], lower[i], upper[i])` tries to access the i-th value of *correlation*, *upper*, and *lower*. This does not work (beyond i = 1) because each only contains a single value which you assign anew with each iteration of the loop.

This works:

```
a <- 1:100
data <- matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 10)

for (i in 1:10) {
  b <- sample(1:100, replace = FALSE)
  temp <- cor.test(a,b)
  correlation <- as.numeric(temp$estimate)
  lower <- as.numeric(temp$conf.int[1])
  upper <- as.numeric(temp$conf.int[2])
  data[i,] <- cbind(correlation, lower, upper)
}
```

A slightly simpler version (while using the loop) would be to assign the values directly to *data*, without storing them in an object first in the loop.

```
a <- 1:100
data <- matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 10,
               dimnames = list(NULL, c("correlation", "lower", "upper")))

for (i in 1:10) {
  b <- sample(1:100, replace = FALSE)
  temp <- cor.test(a,b)
  data[i,"correlation"] <- as.numeric(temp$estimate)
  data[i,"lower"] <- as.numeric(temp$conf.int[1])
  data[i,"upper"] <- as.numeric(temp$conf.int[2])
}
```

EDIT:
Regarding the ggplot-code: Its easier if *data* is transformed into a data.frame and an id-variable is added (if you want the rows of data on the x-axis with text-labels). Also ymin and ymax must be defined as an aesthetic for `geom_linerange()`.

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- as.data.frame(data)
data$id <- paste0("cor_", 1:10)

ggplot(data, aes(x=id, y=correlation)) +
  geom_point(color="red") +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper), color="red") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype="dashed")
```

Comment: Thanks. That works perfectly! Still can't figure out how to plot the output, though. Do you have a solution for that, by any chance?